# What does [nyae] mean in Zsh?

Tags: zsh

I run the following command unsuccessfully

```
dir
```

and I get

```
zsh: correct 'dir' to 'gdir' [nyae]?
```

**What does [nyae] mean in Zsh?**

Comment: BTW: you might want to alias `dir` to `ls -l`, then zsh wont auto correct it anymore and you get your expected results.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

`zsh` has a powerful correction mechanism. If you type a command in the wrong way it suggests corrections.
What happend here is that `dir` is an unknown command and `zsh` suggests `gdir`, while maybe `ls` was what you wanted.

1. If you want to execute `gdir` hit `y` (yes)
2. If you want to try to execute `dir` anyway hit `n` (no)
3. If you want to execute completely different spelt command like `ls` hit `a` (abort) and type your command
4. If you want to execute a similar spelt commant like `udir` hit `e` (edit) and edit your command.

Comment: Wish there was an extra key option that made nocorrect easier, like [nyaei] - i = ignore forever!

Comment: I came here because I thought that `a` would mean "always". I wish it mean that.

Comment: I actually hoped for the same as @RafaelEyng, but I now have the following line in my .zshrc: `alias gti=git`. Permanent autocorrection ^^ (Yes, I have actually misspelled git far too often to bear it)

Comment: I was sure that `a` is always and `e` is never (as its second letter, as `n` is already no). TIL.

Comment: @RafaelEyng Same here, but you can at least disable the feature manually https://superuser.com/questions/439209/how-to-partially-disable-the-zshs-autocorrect

Answer (score 164):

A quick reference:

```
$ dir
zsh: correct 'dir' to 'gdir' [nyae]?
```

- `n`: **n**o – don’t correct; run `dir`, as you typed
- `y`: **y**es – do correct; run `gdir`, as Zsh suggested
- `a`: **a**bort – don’t run anything, and get a new prompt (to type a completely different command)
- `e`: **e**dit – edit what you typed interactively – for instance, so you can change `dir` to `udir`

Comment: I based this answer off of [Ludwig’s explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/800196/578288), but wrote it in a shorter format. This format is better-suited to those who have already guessed how Z shell corrections work, and merely want to know what each option does.

Comment: pretty clear!, is there a good introduction to zsh use? I found that zsh documentation is like 500+ pages, and I wanna know basic usage and regex.

Answer (score 46):

From [*An Introduction to the Z Shell*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html#IDX210):

> If you press <kbd>y</kbd> when the shell asks you if you want to correct a word, it will be corrected. If you press <kbd>n</kbd>, it will be left alone. Pressing <kbd>a</kbd> aborts the command, and pressing <kbd>e</kbd> brings the line up for editing again, in case you agree the word is spelled wrong but you don’t like the correction.